# For a certain insurance company, 10% of its policies are Type A; 50% are Type B; and 40% are Type C:

Tags: probability

For a certain insurance company, $10\%$ of its policies are Type A; $50\%$ are
Type B; and $40\%$ are Type C: The annual number of claims for an individual Type A; Type B; and Type C policy follow Poisson distributions with respective means $1$, $2$, and $10$. Let $X$ represent the annual number of claims of a randomly selected policy. Calculate the variance of $X$:
Attempt: $\mathbb{E}(x) = 0.1+0.5\cdot(2)+0.4\cdot(10) = 5.1$

$\mathbb{E}(x^2) = 0.1 + 0.5\cdot(4)+0.4\cdot(100) = 42.1$

$\text{Var}(x) = 16.09$

Answer: $21.09$

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Okay.   You have noticed that $X\mid\Lambda\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\Lambda)$ where $\Lambda$ is distributed as given.   So you have decided to attempt to apply the Law of Total Expectation .   That was a good plan; just not executed correctly.

So indeed, $\mathsf E(X\mid \Lambda)=\Lambda$ and $\mathsf {Var}(X\mid \Lambda)=\Lambda$.

However, $\mathsf E(X^2\mid \Lambda)=\mathsf {Var}(X\mid \Lambda)+\mathsf E(X\mid\Lambda)^2$, that is $\Lambda+\Lambda^2$.

---

$\begin{split}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid \Lambda))\\ & =\mathsf E(\Lambda)\\ & = 0.1(1)+0.5(2)+0.4(10) & \checkmark\\[2ex]\mathsf E(X^2) & =\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X^2\mid \Lambda))\\ &= \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(X\mid \Lambda)+\mathsf E(X\mid \Lambda)^2)\\ &=\mathsf E(\Lambda+\Lambda^2)\\&=\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(X) & =\mathsf E(\Lambda+\Lambda^2)-\mathsf E(\Lambda)^2\\ &=\end{split}$

Comment: Hello, that means   42.1+5.1-26.01=21.19

Comment: Yes, but why not let the OP do some work?  @DhamnekarWinod

Comment: Thank you so much!